# How to point DNS at a dynamic IP address?

Tags: dns

Bluehost is my DNS provider and my app is hosted on heroku. I'm trying to point the DNS at my heroku app but there's an issue. Heroku's documentation states the following:

> Some DNS providers will only offer A records for root domains. Unfortunately, A records will not suffice for pointing your root domains to Heroku because they require a static IP. These records have serious availability implications when used in environments such as on-premise data-centers, cloud infrastructure services, and platforms like Heroku. Since Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, it’s necessary to use a CNAME-like record (often referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records) so that you can point your root domain to another domain. See examples below.

They go on to recommend creating a CNAME record with the values `@` and your root domain alias, e.g. `hidden-sierra-7936.herokudns.com`.

But Bluehost won't allow this because they want an IPv4 IP Address only and won't accept something like `hidden-sierra-7936.herokudns.com` as a valid CNAME record. I've already done the `www` record and things aren't working, so I'm guessing I need the ANAME record as well.

[image]

Is there any way around this other than switching to a new DNS provider?

Comment: Are you sure that they want an IP for a CNAME record? CNAMEs can only be pointed to hostnames, not to IP addresses. Same should go for ANAME/ALIAS records. Can you show us the error?

Comment: Added an image. Not sure how helpful it'd be. I have a feeling there's no solution here other than switching DNS provider.

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't specifically says it needs an IP, so the problem is in the Host, because there can be a CNAME record for the root domain (@). Try with ALIAS/ANAME to the herokuapp or web forwarding to the www subdomain (which as you said already has a CNAME record)

Comment: If I change `CNAME` to `A`, then the error changes to `Invalid IPv4 address`. I'm not sure what you mean beyond that.

Comment: I don't mean A record. If you do not see ANAME, ALIAS or some web forward / redirect records in that drop-down with the types you better contact Bluehost for a solution.

Comment: @Aerovistae https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

Comment: @DusanBajic you just linked me to the section of the documentation that my question is already quoting from.

Comment: Ha, yes, indeed, sorry :). Anyway, there is nothing much to add: if you want to have the ability to add CNAME/ALIAS to root domain, you have to use DNS provider that supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluehost does not support this. Google and Cloudflare do, perhaps others. Cloudflare worked for me.